# How to search data from database by alias search term?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For Example, I have a table like

```
| id | country | search term              |
 ----   -------   --------------------------
| 1  | Paris   |  light country, Eiffel, tower|
```

whatever the data I search in the search term it has to show the country Paris.
how to implement that table structure for it?

Comment: Please provide examples of what users would search for along with expected results given your example,. Otherwise, I think your answer would be something like... which seems too simple... `SELECT country from table Where "search term"  like '%Eiffel%'`  or are you after a "Full text search"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use full-text search, then this is an example of how you can use a full-text search mechanism on PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE to_tsvector('english', u.about_user) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'you search text');
```

For best performance, you must be added `GIN` index to this text field. For example:

```
CREATE INDEX users_descrip_full_text ON  users USING GIN(to_tsvector('english', about_user));
```